# Store Locator API + Geolocation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to create a Store Locator with the Google API, very similar to the one in the Google examples here:
http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.html

However I've hit a wall trying to get the Store Locator API to get the user's position through Geolocation, so when I click on Get Direction in the infowindow I get directions to the user position; instead of having to type my address in the: Where are you? Panel box.

In the documentation what I have seen is that geolocation is a boolean in the View Option that is set to True by default. But this does not solve my problem.
Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

seems that the googlecode page you said is no longer exist. So I can't give any further insight about what you want to make.

However, by your description, Luckily I made similar site few months ago. It is on [Grocery Store Near Me](https://grocerystorefinder.net) .

The concept of Geolocation is an HTML5 (actually W3C) Geolocation API which is now already embed in most modern browser. It is an API which you can obtain user's location (latitude, longitude, altitude, and accuracy).

you can call it with simply

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, geo_options);
```

Success and error is a callback function in which you can define.
In my case, the function looks like these

```
function success(position) {

  var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // use the lat and long to call function to fetch an API through AJAX
  fetchStoreData(latitude, longitude);
}
```

In the Store Locator schema (like mine in  [Grocery Store Near Me](https://grocerystorefinder.net)), Geolocation is used to obtains user lat and long. The lat and long, then send to server via AJAX to get data about nearby store location.

The server serve an API in which accept lat and long as parameter, then fetch the store data (either using database, or other external API like foursquare), then you can display it either on list, or on a maps.